# Can anyone identify the function that represents this infinite product?

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, closed-form, infinite-product

$$\lim_{\omega \to \infty} 
\prod_{N=1}^{\omega} {{1+e^{b \cdot c^{-N}}} \over 2}$$

For instance, the [Lerch Transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html) is a analogous example of a special function that defines the sum of a useful infinite series.
If it helps,

$$
\prod_{N=1}^{\infty} {{1+e^{b \cdot c^{-N}}} \over 2} \sim \left({{e^b-1} \over b} \right)^{1/(c-1)}$$

This asymptotic is exact if $c=2$. Here's a non-trivial [application](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1326276/219489) of the above.

I'd like the name of this infinite product so that I can learn more about it. For instance, does it have a closed form? I know that for $c=2$ it does. Also, it'd make it easier to generalize the above to other product series I have in mind. For instance, consider the possibility that the above product could be a specific example of a more general function.

P.S. I'd love to name it myself, if there isn't a name for it. Where would I go?

P.P.S Would I have better luck on MO?

Comment: It reminds me of some of the Theta functions. Also, that limiting value makes me think of the generating function for the Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: @martycohen I do see the resemblance with the Theta functions. It'd be rather surprising if Fractals were related to Elliptic theory though.